# Object Property missing even though visible using JSON.stringify

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, object, undefined

The response object of a network call looks something like:

```
{
   id: 'xyz',
   val: 'abc:123'
}
```

The following **if** clause is entered even though the **val** property is present (guaranteed). It is always visible due to the log statement:

```
if (!obj.val) {
   console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
}
```

The log statement prints the following:

```
{"id": "xyz", "val": "abc:123" }
```

This happens rarely and couldn't repro locally. Using NodeJs 10.22.1

Comment: I'm not sure about your problem but if val has a value the console.log will always be printed

Comment: @IvanLynch The issue is that val has the value but the if clause is still evaluating as true. How is that even possible? It does not happen consistently. 4-5 times a day across thousands of requests.

Comment: I think you need to debug carefully each request to check what is comming in every payload. Can you share more information about the implementation code?